# Handle Flickering while mouse drawing Java

Tags: java

```
package first_shape_drawing;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class DrawingProgram extends JFrame {
    private final static int DELAY = 10000;

    Drawing drawing = new Drawing();

    // INNER Class
    class MyMouseHandler extends MouseAdapter
    {        
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
        {
            drawing.mousePressed(e.getPoint());
            repaint();
        }
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
        {
            drawing.mouseReleased(e.getPoint());
            repaint();
        }
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e)
        {
            drawing.mouseDragged(e.getPoint());
            repaint();
        }
    }

    DrawingProgram()
    {
        super("My Drawing Program");
        setSize(800, 400);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        MyMouseHandler mmh = new MyMouseHandler();
        addMouseListener(mmh);
        addMouseMotionListener(mmh);
        setVisible(true);
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        Dimension dimen = getSize();
        Insets insets = getInsets();
        int top = insets.top;
        int left = insets.left;
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, dimen.width, dimen.height);
        drawing.draw(g);
        String str = drawing.toString();
        System.out.println(str); 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        DrawingProgram dp = new DrawingProgram();
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        boolean continueFlag=true;
        while(continueFlag)
        {
            System.out.println("Cmds: r,o,l,s,p,a,q,?,f,d,b,m,g");
            String str = keyboard.next().toLowerCase();
            if (str.length() == 0) continue;

            switch(str.charAt(0))
            {
            case 'r':
                dp.drawing.setDrawType(DrawType.rectangle);
                break;
            case 'o':
                dp.drawing.setDrawType(DrawType.oval);
                break;
            case 'l':
                dp.drawing.setDrawType(DrawType.line);
                break;
            case 's':
                dp.drawing.setDrawType(DrawType.scribble);
                break;
            case 'p':
            case 'a':
                dp.drawing.setDrawType(DrawType.polygon);
                break;
            case 'q':
                continueFlag = false;
                break;
            case 'f':
                dp.drawing.setFilled(true);
                break;
            case 'd':
                dp.drawing.setFilled(false);
                break;
            case 'b':
                dp.drawing.setColor(Color.blue);
                break;
            case 'm':
                dp.drawing.setColor(Color.magenta);
                break;
            case 'g':
                dp.drawing.setColor(Color.green);
                break;
            default: // '?' comes here
                System.out.println("r - drawType= Rectangle");
                System.out.println("o - drawType= Oval");
                System.out.println("l - drawType= Line");
                System.out.println("s - drawType= Scribble");
                System.out.println("p - drawType= Polygon");
                System.out.println("a - another Polygon");
                System.out.println("q - quit");
                System.out.println("f - filled objects");
                System.out.println("d - draw objects (not filled)");
                System.out.println("b - Use Blue Color");
                System.out.println("m - Use magenta Color");
                System.out.println("g - Use Green Color");
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Exitting the Drawing Program");
        dp.dispose();
        keyboard.close();

    }
}
```

How do I prevent this from flickering every time that I'm drawing? I've checked some other questions and some other sites and I can't figure how to implement what I want here. Basically, the panel is flickering everytime I go to draw something.

If this is also relevant, here is Drawing.java

```
package first_shape_drawing;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.util.ArrayList;

enum DrawType {scribble, oval,  rectangle, polygon, line};

class DrawingProperties
{
    DrawType drawType;
    boolean filled;
    Color color;
    DrawingProperties(DrawType drawType, Color color, boolean filled)
    {
        this.drawType = drawType;
        this.color = color;
        this.filled = filled;
    }
    public String toString()
    {
        return drawType + " color=" + color +" filled="+ filled;
    }
}

public class Drawing {
    DrawingProperties drawingProperties = new DrawingProperties(DrawType.rectangle, Color.blue, false);
    ArrayList<Shape> shapeArr = new ArrayList<Shape>();
    Shape inProgress = null;

    public String toString()
    {
        return drawingProperties.toString();
    }
    public void draw(Graphics g)
    {
        for (int i=0; i < shapeArr.size(); i++)
        {
            Shape s = shapeArr.get(i);
            s.draw(g);
        }
        if (inProgress != null)
            inProgress.draw(g);
    }
    public void setColor(Color color)
    {
        drawingProperties.color = color;
    }

    public void setFilled(boolean filled)
    {
        drawingProperties.filled = filled;
    }
    public void setDrawType(DrawType drawType)
    {
        drawingProperties.drawType = drawType;
    }

    public void mousePressed(Point p)
    {
        switch(drawingProperties.drawType)
        {
        case rectangle:
            inProgress = new Rectangle(drawingProperties.color, drawingProperties.filled);
            break;
        case oval:
            inProgress = new Oval(drawingProperties.color, drawingProperties.filled);
            break;
        case line:
            inProgress = new Line(drawingProperties.color);
            break;
        case scribble:
            inProgress = new Scribble(drawingProperties.color);
            break;
        }
        inProgress.firstPoint(p);
    }

    public void mouseDragged(Point p)
    {
        switch(drawingProperties.drawType)
        {
        case rectangle:
        case oval:
        case scribble:
        case line:
            inProgress.subsequentPoint(p);
            break;
        }
    }
    public void mouseReleased(Point p)
    {
        inProgress.subsequentPoint(p);
        shapeArr.add(inProgress);
        inProgress = null;
    }

}

abstract class Shape
{
    Color color;
    Shape ( Color c)
    {
        color =c;
    }
    abstract void firstPoint(Point p);
    abstract void draw(Graphics g);
    abstract void subsequentPoint(Point p);
}
class Rectangle extends Shape
{
    boolean filled=false;
    Point start;
    Point lastPoint;
    Rectangle(Color c, boolean filled)
    {
        super(c);
        lastPoint = start;
        this.filled = filled;
    }
    @Override
    void firstPoint(Point p) {
        start =p;
        lastPoint =p;
    }
    @Override
    void draw(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(color);
        int x = Math.min(start.x, lastPoint.x);
        int y = Math.min(start.y, lastPoint.y);
        int w = Math.abs(start.x - lastPoint.x);
        int h = Math.abs(start.y - lastPoint.y);
        if (filled)
            g.fillRect(x, y, w, h);
        else
            g.drawRect(x, y, w, h);

    }
    @Override
    void subsequentPoint(Point p) {
        lastPoint =p;

    }
}

class Scribble extends Shape
{
    ArrayList<Point> points= new ArrayList<Point>();
    Scribble(Color c)
    {
        super(c);
    }
    @Override
    void firstPoint(Point p) {
        points.add(p);

    }
    @Override
    void draw(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(color);
        for (int i=1; i < points.size(); i++)
        {            
            Point first = points.get(i-1);
            Point next = points.get(i);
            g.drawLine(first.x, first.y, next.x, next.y);
        }

    }
    @Override
    void subsequentPoint(Point p) {
        points.add(p);

    }
}

class Oval extends Shape {
    boolean filled=false;
    Point start;
    Point lastPoint;
    Oval(Color c, boolean filled)
    {
        super(c);
        lastPoint = start;
        this.filled = filled;
    }
    @Override
    void firstPoint(Point p) {
        start =p;
        lastPoint =p;
    }
    @Override
    void draw(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(color);
        //oval is int x, int y, int width, int height
        int x = Math.min(start.x, lastPoint.x);
        int y = Math.min(start.y, lastPoint.y);
        int w = Math.abs(start.x - lastPoint.x);
        int h = Math.abs(start.y - lastPoint.y);
        if (filled)
            g.fillOval(x, y, w, h);
        else
            g.drawOval(x, y, w, h);

    }
    @Override
    void subsequentPoint(Point p) {
        lastPoint =p;

    }
}
class Line extends Shape
{
    Point start;
    Point lastPoint;
    Line(Color c)
    {
        super(c);
    }
    @Override
    void firstPoint(Point p) {
        start =p;
        lastPoint =p;
    }
    @Override
    void draw(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(color);
        g.drawLine(start.x, start.y, lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
    }
    @Override
    void subsequentPoint(Point p) {
        lastPoint =p;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the purpose of your task performer there?? just to have work to do??

Comment: No idea honestly was just trying a few things out. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

Not certain what the right way to do this is but here is where your problem is:

```
    g.setColor(Color.white);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, dimen.width, dimen.height);
```

Here you are earasing the **whole panel** before any drawing, i.e. painting it all white first. This should not be necessary.

Remove those two lines and your flickering will stop.

There will probably be other problems as a result but erasing the whole panel before drawing is almost always the cuse of flickering.

Comment: Removing those break the functuality of my program. Maybe the problem exists within my other class? I've updated the OP. I figured you'd only have to handle flickering on the main panel, but check out the OP.

Comment: @Ben - Then put them back in and put up with the flickering.

Comment: I'm not sure that's the make or break for flickering but I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid flickering you have to paint everything on an image and paint that image in paint().

```
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    Dimension dimen = getSize();
    Insets insets = getInsets();
    int top = insets.top;
    int left = insets.left;
    if(im!=null) {
      Graphics g2=im.getGraphics();
      g2.setColor(Color.white);
      g2.fillRect(0, 0, im.getWidth(null), im.getHeight(null));
      drawing.draw(im);
      g.drawImage(im, 0, 0, this);
    }
    String str = drawing.toString();
    System.out.println(str); 
}
```

You define the image as

```
Image im;
```

and you initiate it in the constructor after you set to visible:

```
    setVisible(true);
    im=createImage(getWidth(), getHeight());
```

Then you have another draw function like this

```
public void draw(Image im)
{

  Graphics g=im.getGraphics();
    for (int i=0; i < shapeArr.size(); i++)
    {
        Shape s = shapeArr.get(i);
        s.draw(g);
    }
    if (inProgress != null)
        inProgress.draw(g);
}
```